# Difference between onBlur() and react-onclickoutside's onClickOutside()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to evaluate the difference between using [React's onBlur event](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) and using the [NPM react-onClickOutside](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside).

I need to be able to hide a menu when clicking outside of it, but would prefer not to have yet another dependency if React's `onBlur` event is already capable of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve it with below code, Using the life-cycle methods add and remove event listeners to the document.

```
React.createClass({
 handleClick: function (e) {
    if (ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contains(e.target)) {
        return;
    }
 },

 componentWillMount: function () {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
 },

 componentWillUnmount: function () {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
 }
});
```

Comment: This worked when I changed it to `!ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contains(e.target)` in the if statement as I needed to setState() when there is a click outside of the menu. Thanks!